# TypeError: sttring indices must be integers in python for splitting variable into 2

Tags: python

I have to make a program for school which checks if a word is a palindrome. I ask for the word to check and want to split it into 2 halves. Here's my code:

```
print("\n \n" * 100)
print("Please enter a word to check if it is a palindrome: ")
word = input("?: ")

wordLength = int(len(word))
finalWordLength = int(wordLength / 2)
firstHalf = word[0, finalWordLength]
secondHalf = word[finalWordLength, -1]
print(firstHalf)
print(secondHalf)

#This is as far as i got
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to use `:` instead of `,`: `word[finalWordLength: -1]`

Comment: @hivert, this has nothing to do with even or odd, "rotor" and "noon" both are palindrome words.

Comment: Why do you want to split the word in halves? A palindrome word reads the same in forward and backward direction, so you might be interested in the Python built-in `reversed()` :-).

Comment: @Jan-Phillip  It just comes back with "<reversed object at 0x02DFEC30>"

Comment: I don't usually send folks to man pages, but if you want to be able to build on this for your next homework assignment, you should read the documentation for `reversed()` http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just got your syntax for string slicing off slightly. Use `:` rather than `,`. A comma produces a tuple, so you're essentially asking for `word[(0, finalWordLength)]`, which Python doesn't know what to do with. Instead, use a colon for slicing:

```
firstHalf = word[0:finalWordLength]
secondHalf = word[finalWordLength:-1]
```

You can also omit the first and last indices if you mean to grab the entirety of an iterable, split in half (and you probably should, since the above code misses the last letter in the original word):

```
firstHalf = word[:finalWordLength] # "from beginning to finalWordLength"
secondHalf = word[finalWordLength:] # "from finalWordLength to end"
```

There's some question as to why you're doing this at all--splitting a word in half isn't an obvious way to test for a palindrome--but that's not really the point of the question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `string indices must be integers, not tuple` because `word` is a string. You can refer to any letter in the word with an integer index:

```
In [84]: word = "amandabee"

In [85]: word[4]
Out[85]: 'd'
```

But you're giving it a tuple:

```
In [86]: wordLength = int(len(word))
In [87]: wordLength
Out[87]: 9
```

so `word[0, wordLength]` is the same as `word[0,9]` and as a string...

```
In [90]: type(word)
Out[90]: str
```

`word` doesn't know what to do with two values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Extended Slices](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices).

```
print("\n \n" * 100)
print("Please enter a word to check if it is a palindrome: ")
word = input("?: ")

if word.lower() == word.lower()[::-1]:
    print "It's palindrome"
else:
    print "It's not palindrome"
```